# Am I responsible for freeing/deleting a string returned by stringstream.str()

Tags: c++

Am I responsible for deleting a returned std::string created by a stringstream?  As in the following code:

```
std::string MyClass::getReturnMessage() {
    std::stringstream msg;
    msg << "Test return code string stream!";
    return msg.str();
}

void MyClass::callerMethod() {
    std::string msg = getReturnMessage();
    // do I need to call delete msg?
}
```

If I'm not responsible for calling delete on the returned value, why not?  What is the memory management model here that requires or doesn't require me to call delete?

Comment: The required memory management operations are encapsulated within class `std::string`.

Comment: `delete msg;` won't even compile.

Comment: `delete msg` wouldn't even be legal. `delete` only applies to pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only call `delete` on objects you have allocated with `new`.

Since there's no `new` in your case, don't call `delete` either.

The reason is that the returned `std::string` has automatic storage duration (since it's allocated on the stack), so it will automatically get destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: So I'm guessing that the returned `std::string` is being placed on the stack as the return value so it is automatically removed when it goes out of scope in the caller.  Is that right?